# How do I install the SIGCHI template with MacTex?

Tags: mactex

Just to note, I am new to latex.

I followed the instructions for installing new latex, bib, and bst files from [SIGCHI](http://chi2011.org/authors/format.html) on the [MacTex FAQs](http://www.tug.org/mactex/2010/faq/#qm04) page. When I open the sample.tex and attempt to compile it using TexWorks using PDFLatex, it renders, but does not create the references.

It gives me an error saying they cannot be found.

Comment: Did you try to compile twice?

Comment: If you are asking if I compiled it after moving the files into place, yes.

Comment: In order to get references, you need to compile the same file twice in a row (the first time for latex to see where the referenced points are, the second time so that latex can insert the references).

Comment: I ran it from inside of Texworks. I just tried it again both in Texworks and from the terminal. I am getting the following error:
...
LaTeX Warning: Citation `acm_categories' on page 1 undefined on input line 136.


[1]
No file sample.bbl.
....

Comment: Did you run bibtex?

Comment: No. I just tried it and I was able to get the references to show up. This is running from the commandline.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To use references in Texworks, you must run PDFLatex, then BibTex, and then PDFLatex to generate a new PDF with the references in it. Say we have sample.tex

The first step generates both a sample.aux  and sample.pdf file which is used by BibTex to insert the citations. Then the sample.aux is turned into a new PDF with references by PDFLatex when you run it a second time.

If you are working in Texworks or TexShop just beware of the steps required to compile a .tex document with references into a PDF or some other similar format. It is a little counterintuitive. You might thing that you just straight from your tex file to a PDF.

Comment: If this solved your problem, then you should accept your answer (click the checkmark on the left); this will move it off the list of unaswered questions.

Comment: @Hendrik Vogt: You are correct. It is done.